# Java 8 : Using Instant, How to retrieve ZoneId information

Tags: java, web-services, java-8, server, java.time.instant

I'm using Java Instant for my use-case where I want to capture the exact moment in timeline for.eg, 
{ When the user last visited my website }. This is when the data gets persisted in the backend (sql). It persists in UTC format as I use Instant.now();

As my website is used across all Zones (In the world), When the user lands on the homepage, I want to show the dateTime (when he last visited the website) as localDateTime as per his zoneId.

How do I get the ZoneId Information?

As my website is currently hosted in 2 servers and both servers are in India, If I do `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, I always get Indian ZoneId (Asia/Kolkota). So, the conversion is not possible.

If Someone from US hit's my server, How do I get the zoneId as US in my server?

Comment: You can provide a `ZoneId` manually, but then you need to determine if it corresponds with the IP address accessing your service.

Comment: You could use the IP address to guess the zone, or use a piece of Javascript on the front end to either convert your UTC timestamp to the browser's local zone, or send that zone to your server to use for the session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best would be to keep things simple.

Just use UTC to store visit time. Frontend can convert UTC into browser's (thus user's) timezone.